# Create label on ServerSide in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, label

I need to crate label from code.

Code example :

```
var lbl = new Label { Text = "Test", CssClass = "control-label text-right" };
```

As Result in html i get `<span>...` instead of `<label>...`

How can i create `<label>...` ?

Should i create it like `HtmlGenericControl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to set the `AssociatedControlID` on the `<asp:Label />` to an associated text. The reason for this is that you usually use a label as the caption for a textbox, as it is the nature of the HTML  tag.

> When the AciatedControlID property is set, the Label control renders
>   as an HTML label element, with the for attribute set to the ID
>   property of the associated control. You can set other attributes of
>   the label element using the Label properties. For example, you can use
>   the Text and AccessKey properties to provide the caption and hot key
>   for an associated control.

Here is an [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in MSDN about  the property !

Comment: yep, this i didn't know. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, if the answer helped you mark it as correct. Good luck with your project :)